# Entity Framework, Code only & EntityDataSource

Tags: entity-framework, code-first

I have an objectcontext and code-only definition of my model. How do i use the EntityDataSource to connect?

Is there a way to define a connectionstring to my ObjectContext class?

Answer (score 0):

Look here:

[How to: Build an EntityConnection Connection String](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb738533.aspx)